# Proof that all extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are of the form $\mathbb{Q}_p[\sqrt[n]{a}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

I'm going over [some notes](http://www2.math.ou.edu/%7Ekmartin/quaint/) that claim that any extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$ has the form $\mathbb{Q}_p[\sqrt[n]{a}]$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. It references Proposition III.12 from Serre's "Local Fields", which states, more or less, that if $F$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$, then there is a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-basis of $F$ given by $1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1}$ for some $x$.

What I don't understand is how to show that this can be used to produce an $n$th root. All we know is that there is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ such that $f(x)=0$. Does that really give us some $n$th root of an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: It is untrue. Where is it exactly

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, let $F$ be the unique unramified cubic extension of $\mathbb Q_5$. If $F = \mathbb Q_5(\sqrt[3]a)$, then necessarily $a$ is a unit as $F$ is unramified. But, in $\mathbb Q_5$, since $\zeta_3\notin\mathbb Q_5$, every unit is a cube....

Comment: @reuns Theorem 1.2.10 [here](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/quaint/ch1.pdf)

Comment: What is true is that every *tamely* totally ramified extension of a local field $K$ of degree $n$ has the form $K(\sqrt[n]{\pi})$ for some uniformizer $\pi$ (that you don't have complete freedom to pick).

Comment: Then every Galois extension is solvable thus contained in a tower of radical extensions, once added enough root of unities it is a tower of 'proper' radical extensions (of the OP's form). Solvability is sketched there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group (injection of $G_i/G_{i+1}$ in an abelian group of units)

Comment: Maybe somebody can point out the mistake (via answer here) to the author of the notes? Would you do that, @SamJaques?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you track the reference to Serre's book, you'll see the actual result cited from there is that for every finite extension $K/\mathbf Q_p$ the ring of integers of $K$ has a power basis: $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z_p[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$.  That does *not* mean $K = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[n]{a})$ and it is stronger than your "more or less" comment that $K$ has a power basis over $\mathbf Q_p$!  There was some kind of confusion between a $\mathbf Z_p$-basis of the form $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^n\}$ and a $\mathbf Q_p$-basis of $K$ consisting of powers of the specific kind of number $\sqrt[n]{a}$.

That the ring of integers of every $p$-adic field has a power basis over $\mathbf Z_p$ is a bit surprising from the viewpoint of number fields, where the ring of integers always has a $\mathbf Z$-basis but need not have a power basis over $\mathbf Z$, a standard example being the cubic field $\mathbf Q(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-2x-8$.

Comment: @hm2020 see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311133/explicit-family-of-number-rings-mathcalo-k-n-requiring-n-generators.

Comment: @hm2020 the ring of integers of every finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ has a power basis over $\mathbf Z_p$. What do mean by the completion of $K$ at $p$, for example what do you consider the completion of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ at $5$ to be?

Comment: @hm2020 that should be called the completion of $\mathcal O_K$ at $\mathfrak q$, *not* at $p$. Different prime ideals lying over $p$ can lead to nonisomorphic completions (maybe not even the same degree over $\mathbf Q_p$).  I already answered your question of $A$ as a $\mathbf Z_p$-module in my previous comment.

Comment: That is the very claim from Serre's book that is in the OP's initial post.  See Serre's book.

Comment: @hm2020  your question has been asked and answered before online: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406117/ring-of-integers-of-simple-field-extension-of-local-field-is-monogenic/3406713.

Comment: what I am looking for is a published proof of examples where for different primes $\mathfrak{q}_1, \mathfrak{q}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$, the completions $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ are non isomorphic and have different degrees over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - can you give an explicit reference?

Comment: @hm2020 you need to get away from Galois extensions of $\mathbf Q$.  Let $K$ be your favorite non-Galois extension of $\mathbf Q$ and you'll find many unramified primes $p$ with primes $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak p'$ lying over it in $K$ where the residue field degrees $f(\mathfrak p|p)$ and $f(\mathfrak p'|p)$ are different. That gives you an example.

Comment: thanks for the response - I would expect that explicit calculations have been published and I'm looking for a reference - do you know of such?