# A question on the completion of a Dedekind domain and monogenic extensions.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

This is a question related to another question on this site (see below) on the nature of finite extensions of the field of p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and rings of integers.

**Question:** Let $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{q}_1,\mathfrak{q}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ be primes with $\mathfrak{q}_i \cap \mathbb{Z}=(p)$ for a prime number $p\geq 2$. It follows the extensions $\mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq (\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ are monogenic for $i=1,2$.

Citation: "..what I am looking for is a published proof of examples where for different primes $\mathfrak{q}_1,\mathfrak{q}_2⊆\mathcal{O}_K$, the completions $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{q}_i}$ are non isomorphic and have different degrees over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - can you give an explicit reference?"

I am asking for an explicit reference to the litteratore on the above topic.
I formulate this as a question since part of the discussion on the below link was deleted and I do not think people will read the comments and respond.

[Proof that all extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are of the form $\mathbb{Q}_p[\sqrt[n]{a}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974259/proof-that-all-extensions-of-mathbbq-p-are-of-the-form-mathbbq-p-sqrt/3974275#comment8890339_3974275)

Comment: I may have mis-read the link below, but it seems that the consensus is that the statement is *false*.

Comment: The idea is to consider a field generated by a root of some irreducible monic integral polynomial $f$ which splits with simple roots in the algebraic closure of some $\mathbb{F}_p$ (say, fix $f$ mod $p$ as a separable polynomial and find a monic lift which is Eisenstein for some different prime $q$). Then, by elementary theory (I’ll try to find a precise statement in some classical text) the properties of prime ideals over $p$ are determined by the decomposition into irreducibles of $f$ mod $p$.

Comment: @Mindlack - there is a decomposition $(p)\mathcal{O}_K= \mathfrak{q}_1^{l_1} \cdots \mathfrak{q}_d^{l_d}$, with $\mathfrak{q}_i$ prime ideals and $l_i \geq 1$. Are you saying that for $i\neq j$ and $l_i \neq l_j$ there is still an isomorphism $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{q}_i} \cong  (\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{q}_j}$? of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules?

Comment: No! I meant “the linked statement (about extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) is false”. It is perfectly possible to have no such isomorphism even with $l_i=l_j=1$. See my second comment for a sketch of a possible construction.

Comment: @Mindlack - If you could write all this (including a correct statement on finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) with references in a post this would clearify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very elementary example, let $f(x)=x^3+10x^2-5x+10$. $f$ is Eisenstein for the prime $5$, so is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $K$ be the number field generated by one root $\alpha$ of $f$.

Now, $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified over $3$, as $f$ splits with simple roots in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_3}$. Assume that the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is coprime to $3$: then, by Neukirch’s *Algebraic Number Theory*, Proposition 8.3 in Chapter I, since $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+1)$ mod $3$, with $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ irreducible mod $3$, it follows that there are two prime ideals $\mathfrak{q}$ and $\mathfrak{r}$ in $O_K$ above $3$ and that the completed field extensions are unramified of degrees $1$ and $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Now, it remains to see that the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is coprime to $3$. But we see in the same book, in the proof of Theorem 2.5 of Chapter III, that the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ contains $f’(\alpha)$. Since $f$ is separable and separable mod $3$, $(f’(\alpha),3)=O_K$, $\mathfrak{f}$ is indeed coprime to $3$ and we are done.

Comment: I’m saying that *I* believe that it’s false, based on what I understood from the comments of the linked post. I’m pretty sure that the result is known one way or the other.

Comment: I don’t know. We might be able to find out by computing the different and checking if it is principal. If it isn’t, then the ring isn’t monogenic.

Comment: Can you give a reference to this claim: That there is a relation between the different and the fact that the ring is monogenic?

Comment: Look up Neukirch’s ANT, in Section 2 of Chapter III, if I’m not mistaken. It states somewhere that if the ring is monogenic then the different is principal.

Comment: Neukirch is a good text on a lot of standard algebraic number theory. But there are a few other books with similar titles that may contain some slightly different stuff (Lang’s ANT maybe? I think there are others too).

Comment: Ideally one would like results like the following: "$\mathcal{O}_K$ is monogenic iff (some condition holds)" - Has such studies appeared in the litterature (not neccessarily in books)?